# pandas: smallest X for a defined probability

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

The data is financial data, with OHLC values in column, e.g.

```
              Open     High     Low     Close
Date                                          
2013-10-20  1.36825  1.38315  1.36502  1.38029
2013-10-27  1.38072  1.38167  1.34793  1.34858   
2013-11-03  1.34874  1.35466  1.32941  1.33664   
2013-11-10  1.33549  1.35045  1.33439  1.34950  
....
```

I am looking for the answer to the following question:

**What is the smallest number X for which (at least) N% of the numbers in a large data set are equal or bigger than X**

And for our data with N=60 using the High column, the question would be: What is the smallest number X for which (at least) 60% of High column items are equal or bigger than X?

I know how to calculate std dev, mean and the rest with pandas but my statistic understanding is rather poor to allow me to proceed further. Please also point me to tehoretical papers/tutorials if you know so.

Thank you.

Comment: sounds like your looking for [quantile](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html)

Comment: thanks, I think it's what I am looking for! I don't understand why the question was voted negative...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, even though the question was essentially resolved in the comment by @haki above, suppose your data is in the DataFrame `data`. If you were looking for the high price for which 25% of observed high prices are lower, you would use

```
data['High'].quantile(q=0.25)
```